# node.js express maxAge setting

Tags: node.js, http, express

If I set maxAge when I called sendFile(), just like below:

res.sendFile('public/index.html', {maxAge: 100000})

Does this mean the file 'public/index.html' will cached in server's memory for 100 seconds? Or, This is just a message send to client side, and server side's does nothing with memory cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`maxAge` is a directive for the `Cache-Control` header. In your case, this tells the client that `index.html` will be considered 'fresh' for 100000ms, so it is unnecessary to ask the server again for that file until `maxAge` has elapsed. The client keeps this file for the duration, it has nothing to do with server caching.

However, who caches what does depend on which way the directive is going.

As stated on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control):

> max-age=
> Specifies the maximum amount of time a resource will be considered fresh. Contrary to Expires, this directive is relative to the time of the request.

And

> The Cache-Control general-header field is used to specify directives for caching mechanisms in both requests and responses. Caching directives are unidirectional, meaning that a given directive in a request is not implying that the same directive is to be given in the response.

Comment: Thank you . That's very clear. And do you know what should I do if I want to make sure my server cache the file in memory.

Comment: @欧阳维杰, the file is already on your server and in it's memory. There would be no need to cache static assets on your server.

Comment: @欧阳维杰, you may want to look into serving your assets from a CDN if you do want some sort of intermediate caching based on the user's location.